# Converting Unicode string to unicode chars in c# for indian languages

Tags: c#, .net, unicode, .net-2.0, tamil

I need to convert unicode string to unicode characters.

for eg:Language Tamil

**"கமலி"=>'க','ம','லி'**

i'm able to strip unicode bytes but producing unicode characters is became problem.

```
byte[] stringBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("கமலி");
char[] stringChars = Encoding.Unicode.GetChars(stringBytes);
foreach (var crt in stringChars)
 {
     Trace.WriteLine(crt);
 }
```

it gives result as :

'க'=>0x0b95

'ம'=>0x0bae

'ல'=>0x0bb2

'ி'=>0x0bbf

*so here the problem is how to strip character 'லி' as it as 'லி' without splitting like
'ல','ி'.*

since it is natural in Indian language by representing consonant and vowel as single characters but parsing with c# make difficulty.

All i need to be split into 3 characters.

Comment: What do you mean "how to strip character..."? Can you show what result you expect?

Comment: don't you see character 'லி' as it as 'லி'. without splitting like 'ல','ி'.

Comment: http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0B80.pdf
Read this... unicode consortium have designed it as so..

Comment: whatever I'm not asking about there design. I'm asking splitting Unicode string to Unicode characters as it Indian language

Comment: I see that these 2 `Char` rendered as one [glyph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glyph) or [ligature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typographic_ligature) - I don't know which... But it still unclear what you want. I suspect the answer is hidden in description of [Char](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char(v=vs.100).aspx) and [StringInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.stringinfo(v=vs.100).aspx) but you need to edit your question so it is easier to understand.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To iterate over graphemes you can use the methods of the [`StringInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.stringinfo.aspx) class.

Each combination of base character + combining characters is called a 'text element' by the .NET documentation, and you can iterate over them using a [`TextElementEnumerator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.textelementenumerator.aspx):

```
var str = "கமலி";
var enumerator = System.Globalization.StringInfo.GetTextElementEnumerator(str);
while (enumerator.MoveNext())
{
    Console.WriteLine(enumerator.Current);
}
```

Output:

```
க
ம
லி
```